# VBA - How to Retrieves the column number and use it to fill another column?

Tags: excel, vba, function

How to make the code work when the Column number is dynamic?

I want the code to work when some of the time i need to work with col B and some of the times is col C (the title stay the same)?

I tried to use function but i don't think I'm doing it right.

```
Public Function GetColumn(str As String, rng As Range) As Integer
    GetColumn = Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Match("Supplier", "POC[#Headers]", 0)
End Function


Sub i()
    NumRows = cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To NumRows
        Supplier = cells(i, 16).Value

        Select Case Supplier
            Case "EDLC", "ANC", "EdTD", "ENC", "APASA P", "EBANROPE", "EVANC"
            GetColumn.Value = "Zaya"
        End Select
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I was trying to answer this, but the code is giving me headache. Could you be more specific on what do you work? How your data looks like?

Comment: whats the purpose of GetColumn Function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Supplier As String
    Dim POC As String
    NumRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To NumRows
        Supplier = Cells(i, Sheet1.Rows(1).Find("Supplier").Column).Value
        POC = Cells(i, Sheet1.Rows(1).Find("POC").Column).Value
        Select Case Supplier
            Case "EC", "AC", "ED", "ENC", "ATHP", "EBPE", "EVANC"
            Cells(i, Sheet1.Rows(1).Find("POC").Column).Value = "Za"
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, it gave me the same error but when I deleted the Sheet1 it worked(no idea why). wrote like this : 'Cells(i, Rows(1).Find("POC").Column).Value = "Za"'

Comment: another question, how can I do the same for ` NumRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row` an write something like ` NumRows = cells(Rows.Count, Rows(1).Find("Staus").Column).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: @DanHelman - `NumRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row` is to get number of rows of data in the sheet, by counting number of rows in coulmn "E". I think your are probably asking for the "Supplier" column. for that you can write `Supplier = Cells(i, Rows(1).Find("Supplier").Column).Value`

Answer (score 0):

The get column can be re-written

```
Public Function GetColumn(str As String, rng As Range) As Integer
    rng.Worksheet.Activate
    GetColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(str, rng, 0)
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
?GetColumn("Zaya", Sheet1.Rows(1))
 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `GetColumn(str As String, rng As Range)` is supposed to return the column in the range `rng` that contains `str`, you can do the same without defining a function. `rng.Find(str)` returns the first cell that contains `str` and `rng.Find(str).Column` returns the column number of that cell.

So

```
Sheet1.Rows(1).Find("Zaya").Column
```

returns the (first) column in sheet1 that contains "Zaya" in the first row.

Comment: thanks, how can i write this :       Supplier = cells(i, 16).Value 

in this kind of fashion:    Supplier = Sheet1.Rows(1).Find("Supplier").Column

Comment: @DanHelman - `Supplier = Cells(i,Sheet1.Rows(1).Find("Supplier").Column).Value` here   `Sheet1.Rows(1).Find("Supplier").Column` will give you a "column number".

Comment: @Mrig I tried the following and I'm getting an error:  'Sub i()
 


 Supplier As String
 POC As String
 
 NumRows = cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row
   For i = 2 To NumRows
    
  Supplier = cells(i, Sheet1.Rows(1).Find("Supplier").Column).Value
  POC = cells(i, Sheet1.Rows(1).Find("POC").Column).Value
  
    Select Case Supplier
        Case "EC", "AC", "ED", "ENC", "ATHP", "EBPE", "EVANC"

         POC = "Za"
  
         
     End Select
       
  Next i
  
  End Sub'

Comment: @DanHelman - What error are getting. And another question. When the `select case` satisfies your conditions, what exactly do you want to do, just change the value of variable `POC` to `"Za"` or you what this change in the column?

Comment: @Mrig Error 91, what I want to do: if in supplier column  cell="something" I want in POC column that the cell = "Za"

Comment: @DanHelman - I posted an answer, let me know if it fulfills your requirement.